# How to write comments to PhyloXML

Tags: biopython

I have imported a Newick file with comments and would like to export it to [PhyloXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhyloXML) with the comments. Is there a way to do this?

I tried to traverse the tree and save the comments and then match them with the PhyloXML, but that did not seem to match.